# Angular toggle property on click and reset it when event has finished

Tags: angularjs, toggle

I have two play buttons and need to toggle their active class on click. When the track is finished playing I need to remove the active class for the specific button.

View:

```
<div class="audio-player" ng-repeat="sample in audioCtrl.audioSamples">
    <button class="play-btn" ng-click="audioCtrl.play(sample.sampleId); toggle = !toggle" ng-class="{'active' : toggle}"></button>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
audioPlayer.onended = function () {
  // Can I set toggle false here somehow?
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've included two ways you could dynamically toggle the class on the specific album, I'd recommend using the directive approach. but as you're making an HTTP request the other might be more helpful.

```js
function exampleController($scope, $q, $timeout) {
  $scope.audioSamples = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "One"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Two"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Three"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Four"
    }
  ];

  $scope.play = function(event) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var elm = event.target;
    angular.element(elm).addClass("active");
    $timeout(function() {
      deferred.resolve(angular.element(elm).removeClass("active"));
      return deferred.promise;
    }, 5000);
  };
}

function exampleDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind("click", function() {
        return element.hasClass("active") ?
          element.removeClass("active") :
          element.addClass("active");
      });
    }
  };
}

angular
  .module("app", [])
  .controller("exampleController", exampleController)
  .directive("exampleDirective", exampleDirective);
```

```css
.container-fluid {
  background-color: #1D1F20;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5% 10% 10% 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-container {
  display: inline;
}

.play-btn {
  margin: 10px;
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
}

.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="exampleController">
    <div class="btn-container" ng-repeat="sample in audioSamples">
      <button class="btn btn-primary play-btn" ng-click="play($event)" ng-bind="sample.name">
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man. The $event parameter was the key. I got stuck trying to avoid touching the DOM and instead find a way to update that toggle property. But in some cases like this it's maybe fine to manipulate the DOM directly.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add the 'toggle' variable to the controller (or directly to $scope).  Either way would do the trick, but I would recommend adding it to the controller.  You can do it like so...

Controller (assuming 'audioPlayer' is the controller 'this'):

```
audioPlayer.toggle = false;
```

View:

```
<div class="audio-player" ng-repeat="sample in audioCtrl.audioSamples">
    <button class="play-btn" ng-class="{'active' : audioCtrl.toggle}"
            ng-click="audioCtrl.play(sample.sampleId); audioCtrl.toggle = !audioCtrl.toggle">
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: The audioPlayer is just a reference to the audio element, so with this solution I'm toggling both buttons. I need to find a way to target only one button when the onended event has finished. Update the toggle property for only that button.